# Startwith in this situation gives me lots of Errors

Tags: discord.js

Everytime I run the command `!ping` it gives me a huge error in my client.js saying that `if(message.author.bot || !message.guild || message.content.toLowerCase().startWith(`!`)) return;` <- this line is an error! Here is the rest of the code:

```
const { Collection, Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
class GiveawayClient extends Client {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.giveaways = new Collection();
    this.commands = new Collection();
    this.ms = require('ms');
    this.fs = require('fs');
    this.path = require('path');
    this.discord = require('discord.js');
  }
  commandHandler(path) {
    this.fs.readdirSync(this.path.join(__dirname, `..`, path)).map((f) => {
      let File = require(this.path.join(__dirname, `..`, path, f));
      this.commands.set(File.name, File)
    })
  };
  start(token, path) {
    this.commandHandler(path);
    this.login(token);
    this.on('ready', () => {
      console.log(`${this.user.username} is now online!`);
    });
    this.on('message', async(message) => {
      if(message.author.bot || !message.guild || message.content.toLowerCase().startWith(`!`)) return;
      const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
      if(this.commands.has(cmd)) this.commands.get(cmd).run(this, message, args).catch(console.error);

    });
  }
  embed(data, message) {
    return new MessageEmbed(data).setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true}))
  }
}
module.exports = GiveawayClient;
```

Comment: Did you mean `startsWith` - with an "s"? That seems like a very simple typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made a small, but deadly typo in this line, the `message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("!")` shouldn't be returned, but continued, after filtering in only the ones that starts with `!`.

```
if(message.author.bot || !message.guild || message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`!`)) return;
```

Also, `.startWith()` is not a function, `.startsWith()` is.
Try changing the code above to this:

```
if(message.author.bot || !message.guild || !message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`!`)) return;
```

This will filter out messages that doesn't start with `!` rather than filter out the ones with.

Answer (score 0):

Just change: `startWith()` to `startsWith`.

It's just a simple typo error, make sure to read the log next time ^.

Comment: I remember when I first started I used to do this all the time lol

Comment: Actually, in their code, StartsWith is correctly capitalised